# w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build/kotlin/sessions

Tags: android, kotlin, react-native

Performing `./gradlew assembleRelease` and hit the issue of this. Below shows the entire error log...

```
> Task :app:mergeDexRelease FAILED
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/path/Desktop/project/android/app/build/intermediates/external_file_lib_dex_archives/release/out
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:412)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:472)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.list(Files.java:3699)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingParams.getAllDexFiles(DexMergingTask.kt:502)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskRunnable.run(DexMergingTask.kt:423)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:335)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AdapterWorkAction.execute(AdapterWorkAction.java:57)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:98)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:198)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build/kotlin/sessions

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/path/Desktop/project/android/app/build/intermediates/external_file_lib_dex_archives/release/out
```

## Some story

During the debugging of this "multiple Koltin" issue, I found out that my NDK wasn't install. Hence I went to SDK Manager and install the `NDK (Side by side)`. Then issue of toolchain occurred, shown as below.

```
No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi
```

Fixed was done by downloading older NDK version, `android-ndk-r19c` and pointed the NDK path in my local.properties.

**Local.properties**

```
sdk.dir=/Users/path/Library/Android/sdk
ndk.dir=/Users/path/Library/Android/android-ndk-r19c
```

---

## TLDR

What I've tried

1. `./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleRelease`
2. Appending the following code + Step 1

```
# FILE 1: Gradle.properties
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# FILE 2: app/build.gradle ( under android{} )
dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

My project env

```
react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
react-native: 0.63.2 => 0.63.2
```

My Project Structure
[image]
[image]

Any idea what causes this issue and how to fix this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

UNBELIEVABLE FIXED, seems to be a `63.x` issue? As there's [another person having this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28954#issuecomment-692684842) after upgrading from `62.2` to `63.3`

The fixed was done as suggested [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28954#issuecomment-632967679)

> Solved this issue by deleting the .gradle folder from /android and again run npm run android, and it solved this error.

Comment: thanks @TommyLeong! good to see you're still actively doing mobile development. P.S. Earl

Comment: hey @CompaqLE2202x as always bro! :) Moving to 0.63 too?

Comment: I'm on 0.65.1. Ive also got this error but if I remove gradle folder then it means gradle wont even run as that folder contains gradlewrapper.jar

Answer (score 20):

seems like running `./gradlew -stop` inside android folder is working for me

Answer (score 9):

Just deleting the .gradle folder did not resolve this issue in my case.

But after executing `./gradlew clean` in the android folder as suggested [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28954#issuecomment-732334233) I'm back on track.

Answer (score 6):

I solve this issue with this solution.

In gradle.properties add following code

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Additionally, insert these lines in app/build.gradle

```
android{

    dexOptions {
       javaMaxHeapSize "3g"
    }
}
```

After making these changes run `.\gradle clean` and `.\gradle assembleRelease`

Comment: finally, this works for me with 66.3

Comment: I did not add this javaMaxHeapSize "3g" and it worked

Answer (score 4):

What resolved this error for me, was **killing all running Java processes** in Task Manager.

I had an actual bug in my code, which caused dangling processes, so I was getting only this error and not the one related to the bug.

After killing all processes & running the usual gradle cleanup, I got the right error message I could work with further.

Answer (score 4):

just reboot!
it worked for my case

Answer (score 1):

```
cd android &&./gradlew clean && cd ../
```

then

```
npm install
```

or

```
npm install force
```

that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin gradle compilation is kind of borken in 1.1.2

https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-gradle-compilation-is-kind-of-borken-in-1-1-2/2527

Add :
kotlin.incremental=false
to your gradle.properties file to disable the incremental building.

Answer (score 0):

i have faced same problem with rn 0.67.2 i tried all options mentioned [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28954#issuecomment-732334233) did not solved, finally i have deleted all java_pid[XXXX].hprof in android folder then all works fine

Answer (score 0):

I use react native `0.67.4`
I followed these codes:

```
cd android
```

```
./gradlew clean
```

```
cd ..
```

run this command multiple times:

```
react-native run-android
```

it's ridiculous but `react-native-maps` package can be the cause of this error. and when I ran `react-native run-android` for the second time it worked for me, but In another post I've read we should it 5-6 times

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete the hidden folder `.gradle` from your home directory and after that clean your android project with `./gradlew clean` and delete your `node_modules` and re-install your dependencies.

I've tried to answer this in more details here: [Multiple Kotlin Daemon Session Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71801534/android-build-error-detected-multiple-kotlin-daemon-sessions-at-build-kotlin-se/72137360#72137360)

Answer (score 0):

I also get this error. and easier way to solve this follow the below steps:

Step-1: Terminate/close the running npm.

Step-2: Now go to the project and clean the project by running this command

*-- For android --*

```
cd android &&./gradlew clean && cd ../
```

*-- For ios --*

```
cd ios && xcodebuild clean && cd ../
```

Step-3: Go to the android folder and ***delete*** the **.gradle** folder

Step-4: Now run the command to run android using these command

```
npm run android
```

OR

```
npx react-native run-android
```

if you are want to build a release **apk** file then run this command

```
npx react-native run-android --variant=release
```

Or to get an **aab** file the run

```
cd android &&./gradlew bundleRelease && cd ../
```

If you are still getting the same error then close the terminal or restart the laptop and follow the same step again

Answer (score 0):

Kill all `java` processes and try building again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was trying to use my phone as an emulator.

In my case **physical device** was running out of space...

Deleted some of my files and build was successful.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).