# Android build error: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build/kotlin/sessions

Tags: react-native, android-studio

I am following React Native `0.67.4` [instruction](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android) to generate keys and sign config before building release package. The app runs fine in Android emulator (Android Studio `2120.1.1 Patch2`). But when building release package, both `./gradlew assembleRelease` and `./gradlew bundleRelease` has the same error as below:

> Task :app:signReleaseBundle FAILED

```
w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build/kotlin/sessions

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
   > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

Tried the following in the [post:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67135414/w-detected-multiple-kotlin-daemon-sessions-at-build-kotlin-sessions)

1. Deleted all under ./gradle and `yarn run android`
2. ./gradlew clean many times

Android studio `2021.1.1 Patch2`, Gradle React Native plugin version  `7.2.1/(gradle 7.4.1)`.

Here is part of `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@ethersproject/shims": "^5.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "^0.2.1",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.6",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.1.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "ethers": "^5.6.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.67.4",
    "react-native-blob-util": "^0.14.1",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^7.3.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^8.5.1",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-encrypted-storage": "^4.0.2",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.7.3",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-redash": "^16.2.3",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.2.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "rn-alioss": "^0.2.5",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
```

Comment: After removing if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {} for release{}  in /android/app/buld.gradle, the error disappears.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was also searching for the solution to the same issue everywhere. Finally, after spending hours on it I came to a solution that finally worked for me, and I think this would solve your issue as well.

As shown in the error log we do have multiple kotlin daemon sessions running in the background.

You can check for this yourself. Go to the `android` folder and enter

> ./gradlew --status

It'll display all the running daemon processes along with the process id and its status. For now, we can only stop them.

> ./gradlew --stop

Now navigate to your `home` directory using the terminal command

> `cd ~`

After that remove the hidden `.gradle` folder using

> `sudo rm -rf .gradle`

Now that you've removed all the daemon cache, you're good to go with the fresh installation.

Remove the `node_modules` and reinstall the pacakges 
For safety navigate to the `android` folder and perform `./gradlew clean`

Now build your react-native project!

Comment: there is a typo `./graldew --status` instead of `./gradlew --status`

Answer (score 1):

Works for me :

```
cd android && ./gradlew :app:assembleRelease
```