# React Native Android: Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'. java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, gradle-wrapper

### Problem

I am trying to build the app (React Native on Android) but it fails with this error:

> Task :app:signReleaseBundle FAILED
> w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build/kotlin/sessions

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

### What I tried so far

Basically everything from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67135414/w-detected-multiple-kotlin-daemon-sessions-at-build-kotlin-sessions), but nothing worked. Which was in short mainy deleting modules / gradle and re-installing / cleaning.

### Code

Not really sure about what to share here. This is from my *android/build.gradle* file:

```
    kotlinVersion = "1.6.0"
    buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
    minSdkVersion = 23
    compileSdkVersion = 33
    targetSdkVersion = 33
```

*EDIT*:
After running `./gradlew :app:bundle --info` I got this additional information:

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeReleaseNativeLibs'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find any matches for app.notifee:core:+ as no versions of app.notifee:core are available.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - file:/home/p/Development/mein-zke-mobile-app/node_modules/react-native/android/app/notifee/core/maven-metadata.xml
> - file:/home/p/Development/mein-zke-mobile-app/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/app/notifee/core/maven-metadata.xml
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/app/notifee/core/maven-metadata.xml
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/app/notifee/core/maven-metadata.xml
> - https://www.jitpack.io/app/notifee/core/maven-metadata.xml
> Required by:
> project :app > project :notifee_react-native

Googling let me to this [thread](https://github.com/invertase/notifee/issues/350#issuecomment-1148969412), but the proposed workaround does not work unfortunately :-(

Comment: Try following this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183674/java-lang-nullpointerexception-no-error-message

Answer (score 2):

Add this to android/build.gradle

```
allprojects {
...
    repositories {
...
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/@notifee/react-native/android/libs"
        }
    }
}
```